# Retornar valor da linha atual de uma árvore da diretiva tree-grid-directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou utilizando o tree-grid-directive (https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive) em uma aplicação angularJS e gostaria de saber como retornar o objeto que representa a linha atual na árvore.

Por exemplo, possuo a definição de colunas a seguir:

```
$scope.col_defs = [
            { 
                field: "Nome" 
            }, 
            {
                field: "Ação",
                cellTemplate: $templateCache.get('botoesTree.html'),
                cellTemplateScope: {
                    executar: function () {
                       // Onde gostaria de receber o valor do registro 
                       // atual(no caso clicado) da árvore
                        executar();
                    }
                }
            }];
```

E na view possuo o seguinte código:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="botoesTree.html">                        
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="cellTemplateScope.executar()">Excluir</button>
</script>
```

Gostaria de quando clicar no botão, ele passar como parâmetro para a função do ng-click o valor da linha que está o botão.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verificando o código fonte, descobri que ao passar o parâmetro "row.branch" na função, ele retorna o objeto da linha.

Por exemplo passaria o row.branch para a função:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="botoesTree.html">                        
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="cellTemplateScope.executar(row.branch)">Excluir</button>
</script>
```

E ele me retorna o objeto representando a linha, na função:

```
$scope.col_defs = [
            { 
                field: "Nome" 
            }, 
            {
                field: "Ação",
                cellTemplate: $templateCache.get('botoesTree.html'),
                cellTemplateScope: {
                    executar: function (objeto) {
                       // O objeto é no caso retornaria o objeto da linha da árvore
                    }
                }
            }];
```